# We cannot modify this step because there are errors in previous steps./A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I got simple table https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Z4h.png
with one invoked function. I do not see error in function
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b9tP.png  or in function view but I cannot add next step because there are some error that is not show.

EDIT
now I see that error appear when I have invoke function before and the error is A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZqbH.png

```
let Source = (OrderID as list )=>

OrderID{1}

in Source
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what's happening for you. I think you are using the GUI to add a column with the *Invoke Custom Function* button. When you do that, you are asked to select a column (actually the table and the column) that you are going to use for your list:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When you do this, Power Query automatically creates a formula with this table and column information to invoke the function:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "test_column", each fn(Table2[OrderID]))`

*But that table reference is actually wrong for this.*

You want to replace that table reference with the name of the previous step. In my case, my previous step is *Added Index*, or #"Added Index" when entered for coding purposes:

[image]

(You can also see the name of the previous step already does exist in the formula, after *= Table.AddColumn(*, by the way.)

So I would change my formula from `= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "test_column", each fn(Table2[OrderID]))` to `= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "test_column", each fn(#"Added Index"[OrderID]))`.

Anyhow, once I change the table reference from *Table2* to *#"Added Index*", the function works fine.